# I want to implement a methode which allow me to prepare a test

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

So i want to implement a methode which allow me to prepare a test automatically
a test is an set of question and the test must be preparated automatically 
So the questions will be displayed in random manner from the database.

[image]

I know that the `sql query` is like this :

```
SELECT q FROM Question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ...;
```

this the package who concern all services offered by Class Test

```
package tn.esen.services.gestion.test;

@Stateless
public class GestionTest implements GestionTestRemote, GestionTestLocal {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public GestionTest() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public boolean addTest(Test test) {
    try {
        entityManager.persist(test);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Impossible de créer un Test");
    }       return false;
}
@Override
public boolean updateTest(Test test) {
    try {
        entityManager.merge(test);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Impossible de mettre à jour un test");
    }       return false;
}
@Override
public boolean deleteTest(Test test) {

    try {
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(test));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Impossible de supprimer un test");
    }       return false;
}
@Override
public List<Test> readAllTest() {
    String jpql = "select t from Test t ";
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
    return query.getResultList();       
}
@Override
public Test findTestById(Integer id) {
    return (Test) entityManager.find(Test.class, id);
}
@Override
public List<Test> findAllTestByCandidat(Candidat candidat) {
Query query=entityManager.createQuery("select distinct t from Test t join      t.resultats r where r.candidat=:cand");
query.setParameter("cand", candidat);
return query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** 
Assume you have a Question Entity for your Question Table, the fetch is very easy, just fetch any (number_of_questions) from a list of questions in the question table at RANDOM.

```
public List<Question> prepareRandomTest(int number_of_questions){ 
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT "+number_of_questions;
  SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
  query.addEntity(Question.class);
  List<Question> results = (List<Question>)query.list();
  return result;
}
```